# R leaftet markerClusterOptions

Tags: r, leaflet

I am trying to build a leaflet map on r shiny with clusters showing the sum of frequencies present in zipcodes belonging to that cluster. The results are just fine.

Now, I am trying to resize the clusters on the basis of sum of frequencies. I want the cluster size to change with each zoom level. And I don't want to hardcode the size. I want the clusters to resize dynamically on the basis of other clusters present in the active visible map area.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the code you've tested?

Comment: freq.formula = 
    "function (cluster) {
var markers = cluster.getAllChildMarkers();
var sum = 0;

var mFormat = ' marker-cluster-';
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
if(markers[i].options.weight != undefined){
sum += markers[i].options.weight;
}
}
size=sum/100;
if(size<10) {size=10} else {size=Math.round(size)};
if(sum<333) {mFormat+='small'} else if (sum>667){mFormat+='large'}else{mFormat+='medium'};
return L.divIcon({ html: '<div><span>' + sum + '</span></div>', className: 'marker-cluster' + mFormat, iconSize: L.point(size, size),  });
  }"

Comment: I am calling this from leaflet function in r: clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(iconCreateFunction=JS(freq.formula)